# Exclude Woocommerce products from a specific product category inside product tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

How can I exclude products from category "spare parts" to show up inside woocommerce product tags query? I want to list all products inside  /tags/, but if that product is inside category "spare parts" just font list it in there. Which function I need to use for that.

I searched the web for that but it doesent work.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? If you're planning to use MySQL, how are these tables structured?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this custom function hooked in `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter hook, this can be done with ease.

> So all products from **`"spare-parts"`** product category **slug**  will be excluded from product tag archive pages.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'exclude_specific_product_category_query', 10, 2 );
function exclude_specific_product_category_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // Only on Product Tag archives pages
    if( is_admin() || ! is_product_tag() ) return $tax_query;

    // HERE Define your product category SLUGs to be excluded 
    $terms = array( 'spare-parts' ); // SLUGs only

    // The taxonomy for Product Categories
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; 

    // Add your criteria
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'slug', // Or 'name' or 'term_id'
        'terms'    => $terms,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Excluded
    );

    return $tax_query;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

---

So if you need this to be used in a **`WP_query`** you will use a similar **`tax_query`** where you will exclude some product categories and include some product tags…

In this example it will output a coma separated string of product IDs:

```
// HERE Define your product category SLUGs to be excluded
$terms_cat = array( 'spare-parts' ); // SLUGs only

// HERE Define your product tag SLUGs to be included
$terms_tag = array( 'special', 'wear' ); // SLUGs only

// The taxonomies
$taxonomy_tag = 'product_tag'; // Product tag
$taxonomy_cat = 'product_cat'; // Product Category

// The Query
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( // The tag query (Include)
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_tag,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $terms_tag,
        ),
        array( // the category query (exclude)
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_cat,
            'field'    => 'slug', // Or 'name' or 'term_id'
            'terms'    => $terms_cat,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Excluded
        ),
    )
));

if ( $loop->have_posts() ):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ):
        $loop->the_post();
        $products_ids[] = $loop->post->ID; // Set the product Ids in an array
    endwhile;
endif;

// always reset the WP_Query
wp_reset_query();

// Convert the array in a string with all product Ids coma separated
$product_ids_string = implode( ', ', $products_ids );

// Output Ids
echo $product_ids_string;
```

Tested and works.

---

Related documentation: [WP_Query - Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: thanks for quick answer, I get error for "endif;" code line

Comment: @DigitalWhirlLLC I have make a big update (I was finishing this answer) and corrected this little mistake… You have now everything to make it yours